# List of dynamic objects with dynamic groupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I need to achieve something like this but I cannot figure how to make it work:

```
class Program
{
    static List<dynamic> myList = new List<dynamic>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myList.Add(new { Test = "test", Test2 = "test2" });
        myList.Add(new { Test = "test", Test2 = "test2" });
        myList.Add(new { Test = "test1", Test2 = "test2" });

        // I need to pass a dynamic list of expression like:
        GenerateGroup<dynamic>(x=>x.Test, x => x.Test2); //groups myList in 2 groups
        GenerateGroup<dynamic>(x=>x.Test2); //groups myList in a single group
    }

    private static void GenerateGroup<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] properties)
    {
       //I need to group for the properties passed as parameters
       var result= myList.GroupBy(properties);
    }
}
```

I receive compiler errors:

> An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

This is only an example of a complex application but at the end, I need to use a list of dynamics and I need to group them with a dynamic list of properties. This is because I read data/properties from multiple PDF sources and it's not possible to use static classes.

Is it possible to fix this error or it is a compiler limitation and I need to approach the problem in another way?

***UPDATE***

I think I've made a step forward thanks to your answers:

```
class Program
{
    static List<dynamic> myList = new List<dynamic>();

    static List<Foo> myListFoo = new List<Foo>();


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myList.Add(new { Test = "test", Test2 = "test2" });
        myList.Add(new { Test = "test", Test2 = "test2" });
        myList.Add(new { Test = "test1", Test2 = "test2" });


        myListFoo.Add(new Foo { MyProperty =1});

        GenerateGroup<dynamic>(x =>new  {  x.Test,  x.Test2});

        GenerateGroup<Foo>(x=>x.MyProperty);
    }

    private static void GenerateGroup<T>(Func<T, object> properties)
    {
       var result= myList.GroupBy(properties);

        result = myListFoo.GroupBy(properties);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and I have only a compilation error on groupBy:

> '`List<dynamic>`' does not contain a definition for 'GroupBy' and the best extension method overload '`ParallelEnumerable.GroupBy<T, object>`(`ParallelQuery<T>, Func<T, object>`)' requires a receiver of type '`ParallelQuery<T>`'

Comment: It's not clear why you're using `dynamic` at all, or expression trees, or what you expect the result to be. Could you give more explanation about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I explained the code hoping it is now clear.

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile even if you used static types instead of `dynamic`. Maybe you should fix that first.

Comment: Good to know Camilo! I'll investigate! thx!

Comment: Presumably your input is dynamic? What's the source, a JSON file or something?

Comment: I have to collect data from multiple PDF files and incapsulate them in dynamic objects. I tried also to store them in a dictionary but grouping and working with dictionary is more difficult

Comment: I have to use dynamic structure because every PDF give me different properties/data so I cannot put them on a fixed class. And 
I would have liked to group these properties using a simple groupBy.

Comment: you can make a dictionary with <string, List<string>> - the key would be property name. Remember to first create a list under given key

Comment: @Camilo: List by all the parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make some changes to your code:

- `Expression<Func<,>>` is not what you are looking for, the `Where` overloads accepted by `IEnumerable<T>` all use `Func<,>`
- There's no reason to make `GenerateGroup` generic if you are going to hard-code `dynamic`
- Instead of passing multiple parameters, you should create an object that includes the data you want to group by

If you mix all those points, you should end up with something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    myList.Add(new { Test = "test", Test2 = "test2" });
    myList.Add(new { Test = "test", Test2 = "test2" });
    myList.Add(new { Test = "test1", Test2 = "test2" });

    // I need to pass a dynamic list of expression like:
    GenerateGroup(x => new { x.Test, x.Test2 } ); //groups myList by Test and Test2
    GenerateGroup(x => x.Test2); //groups myList in a single group
}

private static void GenerateGroup(Func<dynamic, object> groupper)
{
    var groupped = myList.GroupBy(groupper);
}
```